# GNS3 - Connecting Emulalated IOS to TWO PHYSICAL networks

Tags: networking, cisco, gns3

I have a CISCO c3725 router on GNS3 connected to two different and separate unique LANs via the CLOUD/HOST icon, attaching each of the virtual CISCO c3725 to my computer's physical NIC (NIC 1 and NI2.) I have also DHCP installed on both these subnets.

Is it possible to bridge these two LANs together in a lab environment running CISCO IOS under GNS3 on a Ubuntu operating system?

Right now, I am able to receive DHCP addresses from both subnets from each subnet's respective DHCP server. Unfortunately, the emulated c3725 router emulated in GNS3 can only ping via NIC1 to the gateway of its own subnet, but emulated c3725 router emulated in GNS3 cannot ping its gateway. Strangely, it can receive an IP address. What seems to be the issue? Any help would be great!